# Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hibernate-5.x

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1 (It include Spring Framework 5.0.3.RELEASE), Hibernate 5.2.12.Final, JPA 2.1 API 1.0.0.Final .

I have a class

```
package com.example;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;

@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @Autowired
    EntityManagerFactory emf;

    @Bean
    public SessionFactory sessionFactory(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManagerFactory emf) {
        return emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
    }

}
```

Then error

```
Error
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 0 of method sessionFactory in com.example.BeanConfig required a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory' in your configuration.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Are you using any of the spring boot starters as dependencies?

Comment: Yes, https://github.com/donhuvy/sample_boot3/blob/master/pom.xml

Answer (score 7):

If you include this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

You won't have to autowire the `Entity Manager` or provide a `Session Factory` bean.

You would only need to provide JpaRepository interfaces like:

```
public interface ActorDao extends JpaRepository<Actor, Integer> {
}
```

where `Actor` is a `JPA` entity class and `Integer` is the ID / primary key and inject `ActorDao` in a `service` impl class.

Comment: I tend to use full feature Hibernate. Before the question, I created JPA implement of Hibernate with Spring Boot 2.0.0.RC1 success.

Comment: I didn't get your comment, but again, if you are including `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa` in your `pom`, there is no need for you to explicitly provide `EntityManagerFactory` and / or  `SessionFactory` beans. `Spring Boot` provides them for you based on dependencies found in the classpath and configuration properties. 

BTW You are missing `@EnableJpaRepositories` in your `Application.java`

Answer (score 2):

In `BeanConfig`, you should inject the JPA `EntityManager` via `@PersistenceUnit`, not `@Autowired`.

And remove the `getSessionFactory` since the Hibernate SessionFactory is already created internally and you can always unwrap the `EntityManagerFactory`.

Like this:

```
@Configuration
public class BeanConfig {

    @PersistenceUnit
    EntityManagerFactory emf;

}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I catch error: https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/d60b1569144162ea69833d881ef7137f This is [screen shot](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1328316/36632373-a4091072-19b8-11e8-9103-eeb28bee9ff0.png)

Comment: Nope, still wrong. I added an example for how the `BeanConfig` should look like.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have problem at DAOImplement class . When use `EntityManagerFactory` how to query? https://github.com/donhuvy/spring_boot_hibernate/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/dao/impl/UserDaoImpl.java#L22

Comment: I guess you didn't read the manual, right? You need to inject a JPA EntityManager using @PersistenceContext.

Comment: Yes, I am sorry, I don't read user manual carefully. Please point out for me!

Comment: You should read the entire Spring, Spring Data and Spring Boot manuals. For a short reference to using a JPA EntityManager, read this https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#dao-annotations

Answer (score 0):

The specific error you are having is caused by the `@Qualifier` annotation; Spring is looking for a Bean with the specific name you mentioned, instead of looking for any Bean of type `EntityManagerFactory`. Just remove the annotation.

However, once you fix that, and because you are also injecting the Bean in the method that constructs SessionFactory, Spring Boot will generate another error related to cyclic dependencies. To avoid that, just remove the parameter altogether from `sessionFactory` method, since you already injected `EntityManagerFactory` in your Config class.

This code will work :

```
@Bean
public SessionFactory sessionFactory() {
        return emf.unwrap(SessionFactory.class);
}
```

Comment: I tested it and it works, with your POM file. What error do you have?

Comment: After apply your code, this is console log https://gist.github.com/donhuvy/c0c5ef0abbf9130b2bce58b5e2a4bdd7

Comment: Error happen maybe by JDK 9, but I am not sure because I haven't chance to test at this time.